# How to list AWS managed policy attached to a role using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I am trying to list policies attached to a role using boto3. I am using list_role_policies or get_role_policy for that. But it only lists inline policies attached to the role and doesn't list AWS managed policies attached to it. is there any way we can list all the policies attached to a role (inline as well as AWS managed) using boto3.

Below is a code snippet using list_role_policies

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

ec2=boto3.client('ec2',region_name='ca-central-1')
iam=boto3.client('iam')


response = iam.list_role_policies(RoleName='rolename')
print(response)
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to list attached policies, then use `list_attached_role_policies`.

Comment: Also consider using the resource-level [Role](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#role) which has accessors for policies.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think we have anything as such. Need to use both 'list_role_policies'('to list inline policies') and 'list_attached_role_policies'(to list managed policies)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32192011)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same thing today.  Here's some code to make it easy:

```
import boto3
client=boto3.client('iam')

def list_attached_policies(role_name):
    params = {
        "RoleName": role_name 
    }      
    while True:
        policies = client.list_attached_role_policies(**params)
        for p in policies["AttachedPolicies"]:
            print(p)
        if not policies["IsTruncated"]:
            break
        else:
            params["Marker"] = policies["Marker"]
```